# Custom post type pagination is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I am creating my custom theme and there's Custom Post Type too.
However, pagination for the **Custom Post Type** is not working. I tried all the possible solution from Stack Overflow but all in vain.

Here's the code:

```
<?php    global $wp_query;                  
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
        $args = array( 
            'posts_per_page' => 3, 
            'post_type' => 'services',
            'orderby' => 'date', 
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'nopaging' => false,
            'paged'=>$paged
        );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>


<div class="service-content clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :  while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $word_count = strlen( wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content)); 
            $id = get_the_ID();?>                   
        <li class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown animated" data-wow-delay="300ms" data-wow-duration="500ms">
            <figure class="image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?>
            </figure>
            <?php if($word_count<269){ ?>
                <h3><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $post->post_content; ?></p>
            <?php } else{ ?>
            <h3><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h3>
                <?php echo $post->post_content; ?>
                <?php } ?>                                                  
        </li>
        <?php endwhile;
            next_posts_link();
            previous_posts_link();?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here, `posts_per_page` is working but `Pagination` not working , any help?

Answer (score 1):

Please use bellow codes as your need..

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$next = $paged+1;
$prev= $paged-1;
<a href="<?php echo '/page/'.$next; ?>" >NEXT</a>
<a href="<?php echo '/page/'.$prev; ?>" >PREV</a>
```

Comment: Well, it just shows the Next and Prev Links. It does nothing :/

Answer (score 1):

Just use [paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) function

to display the pagination based on your query and paging

```
$paginate_args = array(
    'base'               => '%_%',
    'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
    'total'              => $the_query ->max_num_pages, 
    'current'            => $paged, 
    'prev_text'          => __('«'),
    'next_text'          => __('»'),
);

echo paginate_links( $paginate_args );
```

Make sure the `base` and `format` are correct. based on your permalink structure

Comment: The pagination link showing as `http://localhost/mysite/?paged=2`, which gives error when clicking next. Is it because of `base` or `format` ?

Comment: what is the url of the page you have this loop?
what is the suppose 2nd page? can you access it via direct url?

Comment: I'm actually testing on my local server. I'm afraid I don't have it on live. the direct URL is I provided above. It should be same if I upload it on live :)

Comment: assuming the page you are working is in /mysite/ what is the 2nd page? is it /mysite/page/2/ or did you even create a rewrite rule for the paging?

Comment: To make you clear, I am using this one page template, in which one section will have more than 3 custom posts. There I want to display as 3 posts right now and implement pagination. Right now, my site is `http://localhost/mysite/` and with the code you provided, It's displaying pagination but the next page will be displayed as `http://localhost/mysite/?paged=/2`, nothing changes.

Comment: first try changing your code from ```get_query_var('paged')``` to ```get_query_var('page')```
second test your permalink structure, 
/mysite/?page=2 or url, /mysite/?paged=2 should redirect to /mysite/page/2 as you seem to be using custom permalink, and if it doesn't display anything, then you would have to build a rewrite rule like ```add_rewrite_rule( 
 "^mysite/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$", 
    'index.php?post_type=services&posts_per_page=3&paged=$matches[1]', 
 "top"
);```
paginate_links function only build pagination url structure, the content of the pagination are handled differently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120214/discussion-between-prabin-parajuli-and-silver).

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with pagination in Wordpress is that the Posts per page value is ignored and the **Blog pages show at most** setting in the Reading page of the Wordpress settings is taken as the actual value. So, you are trying to show 3 per page and on the first page that works. However, when you go to the second page, Wordpress is loading a different offset so your code will not work.

This issue has been explained extremely well over on the Wordpress Stack Exchange so I won't repeat that user's answer. You can read more here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-posts-per-page-count

That should sort out the problem for you.

Comment: hmm, does it work on Custom Post Type too ? Well, I changed to blog post per reading to 3, still no change.

Comment: Do the paginations links appear for you using next_posts_link and previous_posts_link? If so, what happens when you click on a next/previous link?

Comment: Yes Pagination links are displaying right now as `http://localhost/mysite/page/2/` but if i click o next link, it says page not found

Comment: That link seems wrong. It should be something like `http://localhost/mysite/services/page/2/`

Comment: Yes, that's right. If I am able to get that permalink, I would be able to debug my issue. so any solution for this ? Did I miss anything here?

Comment: The way that I would normally handle this is to create a page template for the custom post type (eg. Services Page Template) and then create a page in the admin called Services with that page template. Then you should be able to control the pagination

Comment: hmm My problem here is I am creating one page theme. And there are 2 custom post types in home page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120218/discussion-between-andrew-m-and-prabin-parajuli).